# segmentIndex wont be equal to selectedSegmentIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm creating a segmentedControl programmatically where i want to switch between different cell subclasses. Therefor i've created a integer which is suppose change equal to the selectedSegmentIndex. The problem is whatever i do the integer is always nil even though i've checked that the selectedSegmentIndex changes and it does change between 0 and 1. How come the integer are always 0?

First i create the integer

```
var segmentSelected:Int?
```

then i create the segmentedControl and set integer to 0 in viewDidLoad

```
    segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Detail", "Tickets"])
    segmentedControl!.frame = CGRectMake((self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.width/2)-((self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.width-20)/2), self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height-38, self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.width-20, 28)
    segmentedControl!.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    segmentedControl!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    segmentedControl!.addTarget(self, action: Selector("valueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(segmentedControl!)

    segmentSelected = 0
```

then i create valueChanged method

```
func valueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    println(segmentedControl?.selectedSegmentIndex)


    if segmentedControl?.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        segmentSelected == 0
        tableView.reloadData()



    } else if segmentedControl?.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

        segmentSelected == 1

        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    println(segmentSelected)


}
```

Comment: Use the assignment operator '=' instead of '=='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `==` instead of `=`, so you're never assigning the `segmentSelected` variable.